# How to hide imageview after some intervals android

Tags: android, imageview

I am working on an android app in which i want to hide my image view after some interval. i am using this code but it is not hiding. can anybody tell me how i can hide it ???

```
showtrue1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ticktrue);
showtrue1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

showtrue1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: you can use countdowntimer also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html):

```
new CountDownTimer(1000, 100) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // implement whatever you want for every tick
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         showtrue1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     }
  }.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use async Task also to solve your problem . In its backgound function make a thread sleep for particular second and in the post method make trhe visibility gone for your image viiew.

Call the execute method in your oncreate 
 new MyAsyncTask().execute();

and make an inner class as defined below:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
          @Override
          protected void onPreExecute(){
                // show your progress dialog
              showtrue1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ticktrue);
              showtrue1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }
          @Override
          protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids){

              try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            return null;
          }

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(Void params)
          {
              showtrue1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

       }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate thread that sleeps for 1 seconds then call runOnUiThread to hide the view.

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Do some stuff
               showtrue1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
};
```